# WebSphere liberty not running in docker container

Tags: docker, websphere, websphere-liberty

I have a liberty docker container, witch seems to start fine, but when I try to enter via browser the server is not reachable.
I use the IBM Sample1.war for testing to make sure it is not the war file. My problem is that the log file look fine:

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0100I: This product is licensed for development, and limited production use. The full license terms can be viewed here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/18.0.0.2/lafiles/en.html
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0093A: Processing configuration drop-ins resource: /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/configDropins/defaults/keystore.xml
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/Sample1/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application Sample1 started in 0.394 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [servlet-3.1].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server defaultServer is ready to run a smarter planet.
```

And here the docker file:

```
FROM websphere-liberty:kernel

COPY server.xml /config/
COPY build/libs/Sample1.war /config/dropins/
RUN installUtility install --acceptLicense defaultServer
```

I have no idea how to debug without any errors.
Thanks

Here my Server.xml:

```xml
<server description="default servlet engine">

<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
</featureManager>
<httpEndpoint host="localhost" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443"
              id="defaultHttpEndpoint" />
```

Comment: What ports are you mapping from the container to the host, and did you specify a `host` attribute on the `httpEndpoint` element in your server.xml? (`host="*"` to accept connections from any host)

Comment: Add your `server.xml` to the question, link you are using to access app and error you are receiving.

Comment: Hi Gas,
i added the server.xml. I don't get any error just can't call the server   connection refused

Comment: As Iwestby wrote - change host to `host="*"` and make sure you are mapping port in the container and you are using that port (maybe add your docker run command). Also host that you are calling may not be localhost (e.g. if you are using docker toolbox).

Comment: Your server starts perfectly fine, so you only have docker connectivity issues, not related to WebSphere Liberty. You may install WebSphere Developer Tools Eclipse plugin, and it will allow you to develop and deploy directly to docker container.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your server run with no error, and also the Sample1 war has been deployed with web root /Sample1

What you need, as already mentioned, is to:

1. change httpEndpoint in `server.xml` the host="localhost" to `host="*"`
2. make sure you run the docker with port mapping, e.g.

   > `docker run -d -p 80:9080 -p 443:9443 your-liberty-name`
3. open a browser and enter url (I guess you run the Sample1 demo, which has a SimpleServlet in it)

   > http://the-ip/Sample1/SimpleServlet or https://the-ip/Sample1/SimpleServlet

   Above tells that we use port 80 and 443 (standard ports, no need to specify them in the url), the-ip depends if you run local docker container or remote. Enter your ip/localhost if you run local.

I would also recommend to download the [IBM Web developer tools for eclipse](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-IBM_Liberty_Developer_Tools_for_Eclipse_Photon) which allows you to manage the server very easy in your IDE environment.

---

Some good links to have:

[IBM - creating docker container...](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_icp_docker.html)

[Docker hub websphere liberty...](https://hub.docker.com/_/websphere-liberty/)